# How to insert a table of contents into a specific beamer document?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I would like to know how I could insert a table of contents into that document I found here yesterday. This is a mwe :

```
% compile with lualatex or xelatex:
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,etoolbox,fontspec,microtype,ragged2e}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts,serif,structuresmallcapsserif}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,SmallCapsFeatures={Kerning=Uppercase}]{Minion Pro}
\linespread{1.0344}
\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure}
\beamertemplatesolidbackgroundcolor{Snow}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\apptocmd{\frame}{\justifying}{}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}
\definecolor{alert}{HTML}{347941}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=alert}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{informative title}
\framesubtitle{optional subtitle}

 The studio was filled with the rich odor of roses, and when the
 light summer wind stirred amidst the trees of the garden there came
 through the open door the heavy scent of the lilac, or the more
 delicate perfume of the pink-flowering thorn.

\begin{itemize}
\justifying
 \item An item.
 \item An \alert{alerted} item.
 \end{itemize}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: How about `\begin{frame} \tableofcontents \end{frame}`

Comment: It doesn't work. Is it because I have to insert a \section{...} command ?

Comment: `\tableofcontens` displays sections etc. by default. What do you want to be in your table of contents?

Comment: I would like to have the titles of my sections. But even when I add a section content, it doesn't work. Maybe I'm missing my guess, but I think it's in relation with the kind of beamer template I have, isn't it ?

Comment: For me this also works with your desired beamer template. I put the complete code into an answer because it was too long for a comment. Can you try if it works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% compile with lualatex or xelatex:
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,etoolbox,fontspec,microtype,ragged2e}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts,serif,structuresmallcapsserif}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,SmallCapsFeatures={Kerning=Uppercase}]{Minion Pro}
\linespread{1.0344}
\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure}
\beamertemplatesolidbackgroundcolor{Snow}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\apptocmd{\frame}{\justifying}{}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}
\definecolor{alert}{HTML}{347941}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=alert}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{informative title}
\framesubtitle{optional subtitle}

 The studio was filled with the rich odor of roses, and when the
 light summer wind stirred amidst the trees of the garden there came
 through the open door the heavy scent of the lilac, or the more
 delicate perfume of the pink-flowering thorn.

\begin{itemize}
\justifying
 \item An item.
 \item An \alert{alerted} item.
 \end{itemize}
 \end{frame}

 \begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents
 \end{frame}

 \section{test1}
 \begin{frame}
    test
 \end{frame}

 \section{test2}
 \begin{frame}
    test
 \end{frame} 

 \end{document}
```

[image]